# Can I edit a MongoDB object and preverse it's previous value?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

lets suppose I have a model with a field called `draftFields`. It is an object(but it can be an array).

I will create a `PUT` request to add data into `draftFields`. My question is: can I add data to draftFields and preserve the previous vale?

Lets say that I have added the first data to `draftFields`. E.g:

```
draftFields = {
  someRandomValue: 'hi'
}
```

and after that I'm going to make another `PUT` request and it should look like this:

```
draftFields = {
  someRandomValue: "hi",
  anotherRandomValue: "hey"
}
```

How can I do that? Everytime I updated my `draftFields` obj it will remove the previous value. I had to save it in my frontend state to be able to save the previous value. Is there any workaround or method to preserve the values from the backend?

This is my code atm:

```
  app.put('/api/save-draft/:id', function (req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $set: { draftFields: req.body.draftFields } },
      { new: true },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Something wrong when updating data!');
          res.status(400).send('Error');
        }
        res.status(200).send('All good!');
        console.log(doc);
      },
    );
  });
```

I'm using Javascript(ReactJS) and NodeJS if this is relevant.

Comment: You can use an aggregation update - where the previous value can be set to another field, and the the current value can be updated to the new value. See [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the `$push` method and change from object to array.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

I have failed searching, sorry.